# Making Programs With Tabs

Tags: c++, c, tabs, propertysheet

Is there a way to create a program with tabs with C++ without MFC? Just pure WinAPI for example. With Propert Sheets, or Tab Controls. I'm not sure Tab Control is a MFC-specific class or not.

I couldn't find a good example about doing this with Property Sheets, or anything else. Every example uses MFC, but I need a non-MFC example.

Is there a way of doing this without MFC? With Propery Sheets, or with the Tab Control?

[image: Like this one]

Thank you.

Comment: You either have to use *some* library, or write the code yourself.  Those are your options.

Comment: @MahmoudFayez So, how can I create a program like the one in the picture without MFC?

Comment: @BoPersson Can you tell me a library to create a program like the one in the picture? Can ATL be a good choice? How can I do this in ATL if it's possible? Is there a keyword that I have to look for? Thanks.

Comment: ATL is not meant for this. ATL is used for RPC and COM. Please take a look on the win32 GDI library and here is a quick tutorial for it. http://www.gametutorials.com/gtstore/c-4-win32-tutorials.aspx

@BoPersson I think you are right, he has to implement if from scratch

Comment: Here is another GDI tutorial:
http://www.functionx.com/win32/Lesson06.htm

Comment: I saw people doing this with classes derived from CDialogImpl and stuff. Isn't this one better? But, again, I have no idea how to do this with CDialogImpl, either. I'm struggling with old codes for a week and none of them work. I wasted a week, and got nothing. But, yeah, people seem to do this with classes derived from CDialogImpl (at least 3 derivation - I don't know why...).

Comment: See [Good C++ GUI library for Windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/115045/good-c-gui-library-for-windows)

Answer (score 4):

These are basically your possibilities:

1. Use the standard Win32 property sheets, see [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774540%28v=vs.85%29.aspx);
2. Make use of a GUI library that implements it;
3. Create a dialog with a tab control and add pages to it (you would create the pages as child windows and handle the show/hide yourself), but let Windows the deal with the dialog message loop, see [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645452%28v=vs.85%29.aspx);
4. Create a window with a tab control and make it look and act like a dialog using [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645498%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

The last one offers the most flexibility, but is also the hardest to implement.

Comment: Property sheets are exactly what he's looking for. MSDN even has [a sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh298363.aspx). The Resource Editor that comes with Visual Studio can assist in creating these property sheet pages. It's just about as easy as creating a dialog, except for the code you have to write to get it treated as a property sheet.

Comment: There's a way of doing this with CDialogImpl, in my opinion. I saw some old codes doing this. But, I couldn't add command handlers for the OK button and Cancel button. So, I wanted to start doing on my own. Without inheriting CDialogImpl 3 times without any logic behind it. So, do you have any information on using CDialogImpl to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

Of course, it is possible. MFC is just a wrapper around Windows APIs. If you are willing to spend more time developing "pure" Win32 application, then see this sample for Tab Control -[Tab Control in Win32](http://www.pismotek.com/brainout/content/windows_tab_example.php)

Comment: I looked at that example, but because of the lack of OK and Cancel buttons, I passed it. I think Property Pages put OK and Cancel buttons by default. It does not show you the buttons, but they appear in execution time. Like they're in some sort of header file and they appear when your code runs.

Comment: So, you want Property sheets (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774538(v=vs.85).aspx), not Tab control.